# How to restrict CATransition to a specific view instead of the whole view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiviewanimation, catransition

My CATransition code is working fine, but I need that animation limited in width so how to manage this Animation or how to restrict CATransition to a specific view?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what you're asking.

What are you applying the transition to? What animates, and what do you want to do differently?

If you apply a transition to a view, it will change that view and everything contained in the view. The only way to not animate a subview (if that's what you're asking) is to make it NOT a subview, and promote it to a sibling of the view that you are animating.